# No Operating system Detected

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

i am having lenovo g505s laptop with windows7(not preloaded),i want to install ubuntu alongside with windows 7, but it is not showing install alongside option, how do i get that? it is not detecting my os.
i went from bios menu, theres no option like disable secure boot,
boot mode :Legacy
           UEFI
 i have tried enabling both alternately still didnt worked . Need Help,  I Love Ubuntu ;

Answer (score 0):

Click on `Something else` if it doesn't recognize your Windows OS and create the partitions manually.

Comment: That will erase all the data of my hard drive i guess, is it? i have went from that, i have 1TB hard disk, if i go partitioning that will i loose all the drives from winodws os?

Comment: Shrink your drive to create a new partition , this way you won't lose your data.